# Inserção no final da lista resultando em 'segmentation fault'

Tags: c++

Ao implementar uma lista encadeada, encontrei o seguinte problema na função que insere nós no final da lista:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x0000000000400d2f in insere_fim (ref=0x0, valor=1) at main.cpp:82
>   82       if(ref == nullptr) ref->prox = novoNo;
>
> Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   The program no longer exists.

Se eu inserir o terceiro nó da lista através da *insere_fim* o programa funciona, mas se eu chamar a *insere_fim* antes disso, ocorre o erro acima. A linha que apresenta o erro é essa:

```
if(ref == nullptr) ref->prox = novoNo;
```

Já tentei refazer a função e usar outros compiladores, mas o erro persiste. Segue abaixo o código da estrutura e das funções insere e insere_fim e da função menu, responsável por chamar as demais funções:

```
struct lista {
  int info;
  lista* prox;
};

lista* criaLista() {
  cout << "Lista criada." << endl;
  return nullptr;
}  

lista* insere(lista* ref, int valor) {
  lista* novoNo = nullptr;
  novoNo = new lista;
 if(!novoNo){
  printf("Sem memoria disponivel!\n");
  return ref;
 }
  novoNo->info = valor;
  novoNo->prox = ref;
  ref = novoNo;
  cout << "Nodo com valor " << novoNo->info << " inserido." << endl;
  return ref;
}     

void insere_fim(lista* ref, int valor)
{
 lista* novoNo=nullptr;
 novoNo= new lista;
 if(!novoNo){
  printf("Sem memoria disponivel!\n");
  return;
 }
 novoNo->info=valor;
 novoNo->prox = nullptr;

 if(ref == nullptr) ref->prox = novoNo;
 else{
  lista* p = ref->prox;

  while(p->prox != nullptr)
   p = p->prox;

  p->prox = novoNo;
 }
  cout << "Nodo com valor " << novoNo->info << " inserido." << endl;
}

void menu(int* op, lista* ref) {
  int valor, aux=1;
  cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H";
  cout << "                 --- Lista encadeada ---\n" << endl;
  while(true) {
    cout << "\n     1-    Criar lista          5-   Inserir no fim da lista\n     2-    Inserir nodo         6-   Liberar memoria\n     3-    Imprimir lista       7-   Encerrar programa\n     4-    Remover nodo\n\nSelecione uma acao: ";
    cin >> *op;
    if((aux==1) && ((*op!=1) && (*op!=7))) {
      cout << "ERRO! Inicie o programa criando uma lista.\n";
      continue;
    }
    switch (*op) {
      case 1 : ref=criaLista(); aux=0;break;
      case 2 : {
        cout << "Valor do nodo: ";
        cin >> valor;
        ref=insere(ref, valor); break;
      }
      case 3 : imprime(ref); break;
      case 4 : {
        cout << "Valor do nodo: ";
        cin >> valor;
        ref=remove(ref, valor); break;
      }
      case 5 : {
        cout << "Valor do nodo: ";
        cin >> valor;
        insere_fim(ref, valor); break;
      }
      case 6 : libera(&ref); break;
      case 7 : break;
      default : cout << "Acao invalida! Tente novamente." << endl;
    }
    if (*op==7) {
      cout << "\n                   Fim do programa! :D     ";
      break;
    }
  }
}

int main () {
  int op; lista* ref;
  menu(&op, ref);
}
```

Comment: Nereu, isto te ajudaria?(em inglês) [Segmentation fault in linked list implementation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295225/segmentation-fault-in-linked-list-implementation-in-c)

Comment: Acredito que não, Luiz. O problema nesse link tá no **while**, enquanto o meu problema tá no **if**.

Comment: Tem como disponibilizar o código que está a utilizar para inserir os nós ? Isto é, o que está no `main`.

Comment: Tem sim. Acabei de atualizar o post.

Comment: Confirme a edição que fez. O seu `insere` parece ter ficado a meio, sem código nem `}` após o `if` que verifica se existe memoria disponivel.

Comment: Perdão, já corrigi a função.

Comment: Inclua também a função `criaLista` que essa é relevante para o problema.

Comment: Certo, acabei de inserir. Optei por não mostrar todo o código para evitar poluição visual. Caso queira, posso colocá-lo completo.

Comment: Não é necessário, mas a pergunta tem que ter as funções relevantes ao problema, no caso faltava a de criar, pois dependendo da forma como cria o erro ou confusão pode ser outro. O ideal numa pergunta é ter o mínimo de código face ao problema em questão, mas nem sempre é fácil de sabermos qual é.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comecemos precisamente pelo `if` que mencionou:

```
if(ref == nullptr) ref->prox = novoNo;
```

Se imaginarmos que a lista está vazia, e por isso `ref` tem o valor `nullptr` então `ref->prox` representa comportamento indefinido, pois você está a tentar aceder ao valor apontador por `nullptr`, e normalmente esta instrução vai gerar um *segmentation fault* direto. No fim é como se tivesse a fazer:

```
(nullptr)->prox = novoNo;
```

Que não faz sentido e nunca irá funcionar corretamente.

Como resolver ?

Pois bem, aqui tem outro problema, pois na função `insere_fim` o ponteiro `ref` que você tem é uma copia do que existe no `menu` e por isso fazer `ref = novoNo` não altera o ponteiro original.

Duas soluções comuns em C são passar o ponteiro do ponteiro da lista, ou retornar o novo ponteiro para ficar como lista (esta foi a solução que você usou na função `insere`). Mas como isto é C++ seria bem melhor usar algo idiomático, como uma passagem por referência, com `&`.

Outra situação que tem no seu código é que o seu primeiro elemento válido é o segundo nó, pois você para o loop sobre a lista começa em `ref->prox` e não `ref`, o que não fará sentido a menos que esteja a criar uma lista com sentinela.

Simplifique e transforme todo o seu `insere_fim` em:

```
void insere_fim(lista* &ref, int valor) {
//                     ^-- passagem por referencia
    lista* novoNo = new lista;
    if(!novoNo) {
        cout << "Sem memoria disponivel!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    novoNo->info=valor;
    novoNo->prox = nullptr;

    if(ref == nullptr) ref = novoNo;
    else {
        lista* p = ref; //agora apenas ref
        while(p->prox != nullptr)
            p = p->prox;

        p->prox = novoNo;
    }
    cout << "Nodo com valor " << novoNo->info << " inserido." << endl;
}
```

Agora fará sentido trocar também o `insere` para seguir o mesmo principio:

```
void insere(lista* &ref, int valor) {
//^-- agora void   ^-- passagem por referencia
    lista* novoNo = new lista;
    if(!novoNo) {
        cout << "Sem memoria disponivel!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    novoNo->info = valor;
    novoNo->prox = ref;
    ref = novoNo;
    cout << "Nodo com valor " << novoNo->info << " inserido." << endl;
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/aPtMpu)

Algumas notas finais:

- Se está a fazer código c++ é bem mais natural usar uma classe e não uma estrutura. Isto fazia com que pudesse criar uma classe para cada nó da lista e definir um construtor, o que lhe facilitava bastante no código para não ter que estar sempre a atribuir o `info` e `prox` manualmente.
- Não existe necessidade de passar o `op` como ponteiro para a função `menu` se ele não é usado dentro do `main` novamente. Melhor é cria-lo como variável local dentro de `menu`. Não saia criando ponteiros por tudo quanto é sitio. Crie apenas os que são realmente necessários, senão acabar por complicar o código a troco de nada.
- Lembre-se que se criar uma nova lista por cima de uma já existente com a opção 1 do seu menu a primeira fica perdida em memoria, criando-lhe um vazamento na memoria. Logo seria melhor jogar pelo seguro e eliminar toda a lista existente antes de criar uma nova.